# the cardinal number of the set of the relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is the cardinal number of the set of the relations from N to N *N?

I think is similar to all subset so 2 ^ א0
but it's not exactly and I don't know how to take it from there.
I have a test on an hour. please help..

Comment: A relation from $A$ to $B$ *is* a subset of $A\times B$; so there are $2^{A\times B}$ relations from $A$ to $B$

Comment: I dont understand the 'subset'. this is just a 2-order subser becuse it is binary order

Answer (score 0):

Well, the number of binary relations from a set $A$ with $n$ elements to a set $B$ with $m$ elements is given by $2^{n\times m}$.

If you want the number of relations from $A$ to $A\times A$ simply use the above mentioned rule by taking $B=A\times A$. Thus, the set of all relations would yield a cardinality of $2^{n^3}$ where $n$ is the cardinality of $A$.

PS - you may refer to this https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~milos/courses/cs441/lectures/Class21b.pdf for more information.

Comment: thank you very much! 2 ^ (n ^3) is like c or bigger than it?

Comment: @user3523226 What does c represent?

Comment: the cardinal number of |R|

Comment: 2 ^ א0  is c, but how much is 2 ^ (Aleph0 ^ 3)?

Comment: https://mathcircle.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/archivedocs/1998_1999/lectures/9899lecturepdf/Bjorn2.pdf 

Refer to page 5. It states that (Alepho ^ 3) is the same as Alepho.

Comment: I dont understand the 'subset'. this is just a 2-order subser becuse it is binary order..

Comment: And thanks for your last comment

Comment: which set do you not understand? $N\times N$?

Comment: Got it. Thanks! And if it was all relations from N to R it was 2^(C*ALEPH0) WHICH IS C *C , right?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926017/what-is-aleph-null-times-aleph-one Have a look at Asaf's answer. For number of relations from N to R, you'd have $2^{\aleph_1\cdot\aleph_0}$ relations which is the same as $2^{\aleph_1}$